# Understanding 行ってどうすんだ

Tags: grammar, questions, rhetorical-questions

> 「ねー、つれてってよ。七夕だよ」
>   Hey, take me along. It's Tanabata.
>   「七夕なんて**行ってどうすんだ**よ。毎年同じような飾りばっかりじゃねェか。今年はいいにしろ」
>   Go to Tanabata *and do what?* It's just the same decorations every year. Even if they're good this year...

I'm struggling to understand the 行ってどうすんだ part. I assume it's a contraction of 行ってどうするのだ, but I don't know what the function of どうする is here. Why is it not marked as a question with ?/か

Does it mean "what will you do if you go?". I guess I would have said something like:

> 言ったらどうするの？　言ったらどうしよう？ or something like that

Would this be correct? Does it have the same nuance?

I can't understand how the て-form is being used in a place where I would have expected an 'if'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「行ってどうすんだ」＝「行ってどうす**る**んだ」,

just to confirm the dictionary form first.

> 「Verb in て-form + どうする + （の/んだ/んだよ, etc.）」

needs to be remembered as a set phrase because it is used ***heavily***.

This expression actually means along the lines of:

> "***There is no use (verb + ing)***." or
>
> "***What's the use of (verb + ing)?***"

rather than the literal:

> "You (verb) and then do what?"

Finally,

> "I can't understand how the て-form is being used in a place where I would have expected an 'if'."

That usage of 「て」 is common even outside of the set phrase we are talking about.  You can say:

「日本に行って、何をしたいの？」, which is basically the same thing as saying:

「日本に行ったら、何をしたいの？」